# Out of memory mysql was aborted

Tags: mysql, memory

I am using windows 2003 server, with 8G of RAM and MySQL was installed on It.

I am getting error as follows

```
out of memory.[ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 523712 bytes).
```

The configuration which i have given are as

```
max_connections=5000
query_cache_size=16M
table_cache=256
tmp_table_size=103M
thread_cache_size=12
myisam_max_sort_file_size=1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=205M
key_buffer_size=175M
read_buffer_size=512k
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=12M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8024K
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_log_file_size=170M
innodb_thread_concurrency=24
```

Can any one please tell me the solution.?why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem most of the time is buffer_pool_size, key_buffer_size , etc in My.cnf
This in depth post from @RolandoMySQLDBA should solve your problem:

[Why does MySQL say I'm out of memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/why-does-mysql-say-im-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your settings I see a few disturbing trends

You have `tmp_table_size=103M` and `max_connections=5000`

That's a maximum of 515000M (103M per connection X 5000) = 503G in tmp tables alone.

Other per-connection settings that are multiplied by 5000 as is explained in [How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-costly-is-opening-and-closing-of-a-db-connection/16973#16973)

At the very least, lower the max_connections to 500 for starters