# MariaDB Spider Engine Out of Memory

Tags: mysql, mariadb, memory, storage-engine, spider

I had almost standard MariaDB with InnoDB engine working fine but I wanted to test out the Spider Engine + Sharding/Partitioning. I had a query which was passing fine on the MariaDB InnoDB for 15-20min. With Spider engine no matter what I do it always gets to out of memory.
The setup with spider engine is that I have 1 spider engine with 2 backends with proper partitioning on both.

Where I am mistaking. What should I change in my config.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%spider%';
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                         | Value     |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| spider_auto_increment_mode            | -1        |
| spider_bgs_first_read                 | -1        |
| spider_bgs_mode                       | 3         |
| spider_bgs_second_read                | -1        |
| spider_bka_engine                     |           |
| spider_bka_mode                       | 1         |
| spider_bka_table_name_type            | -1        |
| spider_block_size                     | 16384     |
| spider_bulk_size                      | -1        |
| spider_bulk_update_mode               | -1        |
| spider_bulk_update_size               | 128000000 |
| spider_casual_read                    | -1        |
| spider_conn_recycle_mode              | 1         |
| spider_conn_recycle_strict            | 0         |
| spider_connect_mutex                  | OFF       |
| spider_connect_retry_count            | 1000      |
| spider_connect_retry_interval         | 1000      |
| spider_connect_timeout                | 28000     |
| spider_crd_bg_mode                    | -1        |
| spider_crd_interval                   | -1        |
| spider_crd_mode                       | -1        |
| spider_crd_sync                       | -1        |
| spider_crd_type                       | -1        |
| spider_crd_weight                     | -1        |
| spider_delete_all_rows_type           | -1        |
| spider_direct_dup_insert              | -1        |
| spider_direct_order_limit             | 1         |
| spider_dry_access                     | OFF       |
| spider_error_read_mode                | -1        |
| spider_error_write_mode               | -1        |
| spider_first_read                     | -1        |
| spider_force_commit                   | 1         |
| spider_general_log                    | OFF       |
| spider_init_sql_alloc_size            | -1        |
| spider_internal_limit                 | -1        |
| spider_internal_offset                | -1        |
| spider_internal_optimize              | -1        |
| spider_internal_optimize_local        | -1        |
| spider_internal_sql_log_off           | OFF       |
| spider_internal_unlock                | OFF       |
| spider_internal_xa                    | OFF       |
| spider_internal_xa_id_type            | 0         |
| spider_internal_xa_snapshot           | 0         |
| spider_local_lock_table               | OFF       |
| spider_lock_exchange                  | OFF       |
| spider_log_result_error_with_sql      | 0         |
| spider_log_result_errors              | 0         |
| spider_low_mem_read                   | 1         |
| spider_max_order                      | 32767     |
| spider_multi_split_read               | 1         |
| spider_net_read_timeout               | 28000     |
| spider_net_write_timeout              | -1        |
| spider_ping_interval_at_trx_start     | 3600      |
| spider_quick_mode                     | 3         |
| spider_quick_page_size                | 8096      |
| spider_read_only_mode                 | -1        |
| spider_remote_access_charset          |           |
| spider_remote_autocommit              | 1         |
| spider_remote_default_database        |           |
| spider_remote_sql_log_off             | 0         |
| spider_remote_time_zone               |           |
| spider_remote_trx_isolation           | -1        |
| spider_reset_sql_alloc                | -1        |
| spider_same_server_link               | OFF       |
| spider_second_read                    | -1        |
| spider_select_column_mode             | -1        |
| spider_selupd_lock_mode               | -1        |
| spider_semi_split_read                | 8         |
| spider_semi_split_read_limit          | 8         |
| spider_semi_table_lock                | 1         |
| spider_semi_table_lock_connection     | -1        |
| spider_semi_trx                       | ON        |
| spider_semi_trx_isolation             | -1        |
| spider_skip_default_condition         | -1        |
| spider_split_read                     | -1        |
| spider_sts_bg_mode                    | -1        |
| spider_sts_interval                   | -1        |
| spider_sts_mode                       | -1        |
| spider_sts_sync                       | -1        |
| spider_support_xa                     | ON        |
| spider_sync_autocommit                | ON        |
| spider_sync_time_zone                 | OFF       |
| spider_sync_trx_isolation             | ON        |
| spider_table_init_error_interval      | 1         |
| spider_udf_ct_bulk_insert_interval    | -1        |
| spider_udf_ct_bulk_insert_rows        | -1        |
| spider_udf_ds_bulk_insert_rows        | -1        |
| spider_udf_ds_table_loop_mode         | -1        |
| spider_udf_ds_use_real_table          | -1        |
| spider_udf_table_lock_mutex_count     | 20        |
| spider_udf_table_mon_mutex_count      | 20        |
| spider_use_all_conns_snapshot         | OFF       |
| spider_use_consistent_snapshot        | OFF       |
| spider_use_default_database           | ON        |
| spider_use_flash_logs                 | OFF       |
| spider_use_handler                    | -1        |
| spider_use_pushdown_udf               | -1        |
| spider_use_snapshot_with_flush_tables | 0         |
| spider_use_table_charset              | -1        |
| spider_version                        | 3.2.21    |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please show us two things: 1) The Query, 2) The Table Structures for the Query

Comment: RolandoMySQLDBA thank you very much for your reply. I have updated the initial post with the create view and create table. For the test If I apply the query to backend1 or backend2 it passes (no out of memory). If I run it against the spider node it's eaten up the entire memory and at the end dies with kernel killing mysqld/mariadb.

Answer (score 2):

## DISCLAIMER : Not a Spider Storage Engine Expert

I don't think the Query is totally the problem. It is not the Spider Storage Engine (SSE) as a whole. There is one particular aspect of the SSE that you should be concerned with: The DB Connection to each shard.

Think about how a DB Connection allocates memory.

Here are the buffers associated with a single DB Connection:

- [join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)
- [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)
- [read_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_buffer_size)
- [read_rnd_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size)
- [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) / [max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size)
- [net_buffer_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) / [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)
- [thread_stack](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack)

Given SSE has to maintain an open connection to both shards, picture what is happening:

- Data being read from the 1st shard
- DB Connection is holding some memory in the sort buffer
- Data being read from the 2nd shard
- DB Connection is holding some memory in the sort buffer

While both of these connections are holding its share of the data, the aggregation is being done.

Here are my past posts on the memory consumption of DB Connections

- `Apr 24, 2012` : [How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-costly-is-opening-and-closing-of-a-db-connection/16973#16973)
- `Apr 25, 2012` : [Out of memory mysql was aborted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16988/out-of-memory-mysql-was-aborted/17059#17059)
- `Oct 01, 2014` : [Do threads in cache still use memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78167/do-threads-in-cache-still-use-memory/78178#78178)

As for the query, you are generating a whole result then siphoning off 10 million rows. Chances are, the memory from the two DB Connections is not being released until the query is done.

Why would the query against the InnoDB version of the data work ? Most likely, any temp table generated would have eventually been written to disk to continue processing the whole result set, all of this being done in one DB Connection.

You may have to lower some of the buffer sizes to make the DB Connection go to disk or get quadruple the amount of RAM. Please spend some time tuning them.

One more thing: Aggregating against a View is sure to create large temp tables. Try to refactor the query to retrieve less rows, even in the case of InnoDB.